# MongoDB: Return objects filtered into arrays that share same key value

Tags: database, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have collection of data called events. Each event has location property on itself witch is a object that has latitude and longitude values. I want to return them sorted into arrays that share same values for latitude and longitude. I'm not sure if this is possible.

For instance, this is my collection:

```
[
    {
        "location": {
            "latitude": 100,
            "longitude": 50,

        },
        "_id": "649ee842b403775f5f8b8829",
        ...
    },
    {
        "location": {
            "latitude": 44.772182,
            "longitude": 17.191,
        },
        "_id": "64a0529efa2f1621a9d17e16",
       ...
    },
    {
        "location": {
            "latitude": 23,
            "longitude": 61,
        },
        "_id": "64b4ed77a0fa0d993844a60b",
        ...
    },
    {
        "location": {
            "latitude": 100,
            "longitude": 50,
        },
        "_id": "64b680f88a2a664d134025c9",
        ...
    },
    {
        "location": {
            "latitude": 32,
            "longitude": 18,
        },
        "_id": "64b681028a2a664d134025cc",
        ...
    },
    {
        "location": {
            "latitude": 44.772182,
            "longitude": 17.191,
        },
        "_id": "64a05305fa2f1621a9d17e1b",
         ...
    },
]
```

I want to return this:

```
[
    [
        {
            "location": {
                "latitude": 100,
                "longitude": 50,
    
            },
            "_id": "649ee842b403775f5f8b8829",
            ...
        },
        {
            "location": {
                "latitude": 100,
                "longitude": 50,
            },
            "_id": "64b680f88a2a664d134025c9",
            ...
        },
    ],
    [
        {
            "location": {
                "latitude": 44.772182,
                "longitude": 17.191,
            },
            "_id": "64a0529efa2f1621a9d17e16",
           ...
        },
        {
            "location": {
                "latitude": 44.772182,
                "longitude": 17.191,
            },
            "_id": "64a05305fa2f1621a9d17e1b",
             ...
        },
    ],
    [
         {
            "location": {
                "latitude": 32,
                "longitude": 18,
            },
            "_id": "64b681028a2a664d134025cc",
            ...
        },
    ],
    [
        {
            "location": {
                "latitude": 23,
                "longitude": 61,
            },
            "_id": "64b4ed77a0fa0d993844a60b",
            ...
        }
    ]
]
```

Comment: This can probably be accomplished by `$group`, I'm just a little confused on the requested structure that you want returned. Should each document in the returned data have a field which is an array containing the related documents? Do you want all data (how much) to come back in a single document that contains these arrays? Something else?

Comment: I want to return single array for every unique location value in my documents, and that array will contain every document with that location value

Answer (score 0):

you can't have array as root of your results.

But you can have something as follows:

```
[
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "_id": "64b4ed77a0fa0d993844a60b",
        "location": {
          "latitude": 23,
          "longitude": 61
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "_id": "64a0529efa2f1621a9d17e16",
        "location": {
          "latitude": 44.772182,
          "longitude": 17.191
        }
      },
      {
        "_id": "64a05305fa2f1621a9d17e1b",
        "location": {
          "latitude": 44.772182,
          "longitude": 17.191
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "_id": "64b681028a2a664d134025cc",
        "location": {
          "latitude": 32,
          "longitude": 18
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "_id": "649ee842b403775f5f8b8829",
        "location": {
          "latitude": 100,
          "longitude": 50
        }
      },
      {
        "_id": "64b680f88a2a664d134025c9",
        "location": {
          "latitude": 100,
          "longitude": 50
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

You can achieve this with a simple aggregation pipeline:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$location",
      "data": {
        "$push": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "_id"
  }
])
```

You can check it out on mongoplayground https://mongoplayground.net/p/VLuOlkmajML